# Box2d Lights || Conelight Passes Over Body When Colliding

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

thanks for reading my post. I am using box2d lights, and it is mostly working good, except for 1 problem. When A conelight goes ontop of a body that light collides with, the light passes over the object. I want to make it so that if the conelight collides with a body, it doesn't pass over the object, but instead not render. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

did you try light.setXray(false) ?

Answer (score 0):

Box2dLights uses RayCasting to check if some object has to drop a shadow. As this raycasts ignore shapes on their starting point, the object right under your light will never drop a shadow. Instead you have to query the world yourself and switch your light off, if there is a shape on that point.